# Angular 2 http why does response.json() return a json string?

Tags: angular, rxjs

Building my first Angular 2 app, the http module is not doing what i expected it to do.

```js
getHeroes (): Observable<Hero[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
                .map(this.extractData)
                .catch(this.handleError);
}


private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body.data || { };
}
```

The `res.json()` calls `json.parse()` and I was expecting an object back but I just get the json string the server gave me.

Not sure how I managed to mess this up, anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

ok, i'm dumb...

my api method (node.js)...

res.json(JSON.stringify(data));

would have expected an error when the parser tried to parse that mess.